# Correct path or permissions for Rails app? - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, ubuntu-16.04

The following model method in a Rails application that calls the Carrierwave gem functionality

```
  before_save :generate_firma

  def generate_firma
    unless self.signature.nil?
      instructions = self.signature.map { |h| "line #{h['mx'].to_i},#{h['my'].to_i} #{h['lx'].to_i},#{h['ly'].to_i}" } * ' '
      path_signature_image="tmp/"+self.intervento_id.to_s+self.sequence+".png"
      puts path_signature_image
      system "convert -size 1010x395 xc:transparent -stroke blue -draw '#{instructions}' #{path_signature_image}"
      self.firma = File.open(path_signature_image)
    end
  end
```

generates an error `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - tmp/58iniziofirma.png` upon execution highlighting the error on line `self.firma[...]`.
This is happening upon migration of the application to a new server using Ubuntu 16.04 **on the  old server Ubuntu 14.04, the file loads properly to S3**.

As the previous version loads, I assume the biggest culprit is a permissions issue, as each server instance has a tmp directory at the root level, user level and at the release level.

Yet, permission are identical on both servers:

```
drwxrwxrwt  (root level)
drwxrwxr-x  (user level)
drwxrwxr-x  (current release level)
```

how can this get resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New server? So ask the question what is different?

It took a few banged walls to figure out an important component had not been installed on the server. [Whatever documentation there is out there](https://github.com/thread-pond/signature-pad) it does not state that `imagemagick` needs to be installed.